# Setting the focus for the user

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

If the user begins typing, and the focus happens to not be on the only input control I have on the page, how can I set the focus to be on that input control in order to create a better user experience?

There are things that can have the focus, such as if the user tabs to a hyperlink or mouse clicks outside the input.

Comment: You probably want to set the focus on page load so the user can see where the cursor is instead of changing the focus on demand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('body').keydown(function() { $('input').focus(); });
```